# MySQL server shuts down immediately after starting

Tags: mysql

I had MySQL Workbench installed, I was trying to make a script and open .sql files of database I got sent over (I am a noob practising), later on I realised my local server was off, I tried win + R and running on services.msc but it shuts itself down in like two seconds I start it. Can someone help please?

From general event viewer:

> Faulting application name: mysqld.exe, version: 8.0.20.0, time stamp: 0x5e7ccc72 Faulting module name: mysqld.exe, version: 8.0.20.0, time stamp: 0x5e7ccc72 Exception code: 0x80000003 Fault offset: 0x0000000000edde82 Faulting process id: 0x561c Faulting application start time: 0x01d6246453fe6ef2 Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe Report Id: 6915f4a7-a9e5-4606-a6ce-1c52ede111c7 Faulting package full name: Faulting package-relative application ID:

From details:
 mysqld.exe 
   8.0.20.0 
   5e7ccc72 
   mysqld.exe 
   8.0.20.0 
   5e7ccc72 
   80000003 
   0000000000edde82 
   561c 
   01d6246453fe6ef2 
   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe 
   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe 
   6915f4a7-a9e5-4606-a6ce-1c52ede111c7

Comment: Look in the Windows Event Viewer for error messages from MYSQL. That shoudl help you work out the issue. If not post the error message here and we will have a go :)

Comment: Is this it?
Faulting application name: mysqld.exe, version: 8.0.20.0, time stamp: 0x5e7ccc72
Faulting module name: mysqld.exe, version: 8.0.20.0, time stamp: 0x5e7ccc72
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x0000000000edde82
Faulting process id: 0x561c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6246453fe6ef2
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe
Report Id: 6915f4a7-a9e5-4606-a6ce-1c52ede111c7
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Put stuff like that in the question, using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61656871/edit) are there any others?

Comment: Edited and saved what I found. First time in StackOverflow, sorry

Comment: The Exception code: 0x80000003 suggests an error with the installation, I would try uninstalling and reinstalling it.

Comment: I already did that, uninstalled and reinstalled everything i found MySQL related, but I will try again now, thank you

Comment: Yep, everything is fixed once reinstalled for the third time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in the end I just reinstalled everything and made sure to delete hidden files (guess that was the problem).